# close button not closing the whole application in c# with Paddle SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, sdk, csharpcodeprovider

Actually I integrated the paddle sdk with C# with all configuration and everything working fine but the problem is that when anyone click on close control of Form then whole application in Windows Form should be close and here another thing is that paddle has also option to use software with trial also. Here below picture is given for my scenario. Front form to activate first but anyone will click on Cross control then whole application should be close automatically. But now what's happening here only front form closing and anyone can use software without activation.

[image]

Here is source code you can check:

```
 var productInfo = new PaddleSDK.Product.PaddleProductConfig { ProductName = "ScrapeVerify", VendorName = "ScrapeVerify" };
        Paddle.Configure(paddle_apiKey, paddle_vendorId, paddle_productId, productInfo);
        Paddle.Instance.TransactionCompleteEvent += Paddle_TransactionCompleteEvent;
        Paddle.Instance.TransactionErrorEvent += Paddle_TransactionErrorEvent;
        Paddle.Instance.TransactionBeginEvent += Paddle_TransactionBeginEvent;

        PaddleProduct product = PaddleProduct.CreateProduct(paddle_productId);

        product.Refresh((success) =>
        {
            if (success)
            {

                if (!product.Activated)
                {
                    Paddle.Instance.ShowProductAccessWindowForProduct(product);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Paddle.Instance.ShowProductAccessWindowForProduct(product);
            }

            Application.Exit();

        });
```

Comment: Have you tried calling Application.Exit(); on closing event of the form that should close the whole application as well?

Comment: actually don't know the closing event of sdk the problem is that. Application.Exit() is working but I need to call this when anyone closes the first form of payment or of activation which showing then the whole application should be closed automatically.